# duplicate entry: com/google/zxing/aztec/AztecDetectorResult.class

Tags: android, cordova, zxing

I'm facing this [issue](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/662) but I don't know where to put the code to resolve it:

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'){ exclude group: 'com.google.zxing' }
```

I'm using Cordova and the plugins that are conflicting are facebook4 and barcodescanner according to the thread on GitHub.
Does anyone have a clue ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like since the new integration of zxing in the Facebook SDK, conflicts recently appeared with cordova-plugin-barcode-scanner and cordova-plugin-facebook4.

Like stated in [this thread](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/535#issuecomment-325153055), the issue is resolved by forcing the version of Facebook SDK to 4.25.0.

I did this in the file `project.properties` in `platforms/android/` by changing the line

`cordova.system.library.2=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+`

to

`cordova.system.library.2=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0`.

Hope this will help some :)